# Access denied in Maven

Tags: maven-3

I have following problem with Maven:

When I perform `mvn jetty:run` I'm getting:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: http://10.254.107.3:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot/org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-api/2.1-6.0.1/jsp-api-2.1-6.0.1.pom, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:835)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
```

We found that my MVN client is using monitor user for connection (it's doing sometimes for `clean install` too, according to log, but typically that is not blocker).

I have in my `settings.xml`:

```xml
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>releases</id>
      <username>monitor</username>
      <password>...</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <username>monitor</username>
      <password>...</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

so I think (but I'm not Maven guru), that this shouldn't be used for `plugins-snapshot`.

AFAIK my configuration is same for all guys in team and I'm the only one with such problem. In fact I have no idea why that happens.

I'm switching Maven 2 and Maven 3 regularly, maybe that is the reason. How am I doing this? I'm using Windows (Win7) and when I need to switch I simply change `M2_HOME` environment property to correct Maven home and replace `settings.xml` for Maven 2 with the one for Maven 3 in my user home and vice versa. My `settings.xml` for Maven 2 does not contain `<servers>` part.

Any idea how to track where the problem is is appreciated.

Comment: Exactly missing the server entries in the settings is causing the thing cause you got the hint "Forbidden"

Comment: as I understood from our server admin, I shouldn't use credentials, but maven sends it...

Comment: If it's so just remove the server entries from settings.xml and retry.

Comment: yeah, that works, but in case when I want to update from snapshot I have access denied :-(

Comment: That sounds your configuration is simply wrong.